# Date and calendar java

Tags: java

```
class Employee
{
private Date doj;

public Employee (Date doj)
{
this.doj=doj;
}
public Date getDoj()
{
return doj;
}
}


class TestEmployeeSort
{
public static List<Employee> getEmployees()
{
  List<Employee> col=new ArrayList<Employee>();
  col.add(new Employee(new Date(1986,21,22));
}
}
```

In the above code i have used Date to set a date. I want to know how to use calendar function to do this. I know that i can use getInstance() and set the date. But I don't know how to implement it. Please help me to know how to set Date using Calendar function

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 & Java 9. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 2):

## tl;dr

```
LocalDate.of( 1986 , Month.FEBRUARY , 23 )
```

## Date-only

Neither of those classes, `Date` & `Calendar`, are suitable.

You apparently want a date-only value without a time-of-day and without a time zone. In contrast, the `Date` class is a date with a time-of-day in UTC, and `Calendar` is a date-time with a time zone.

Furthermore, both `Date` & `Calendar` are obsolete, replaced by the *java.time* classes.

### `LocalDate`

The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone.

#### Today

A time zone is crucial in determining a date. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by zone. For example, a few minutes after midnight in [Paris France](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europe/Paris) is a new day while still “yesterday” in [Montréal Québec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal).

If no time zone is specified, the JVM implicitly applies its current default time zone. That default may change at any moment, so your results may vary. Better to specify your desired/expected time zone explicitly as an argument.

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal), [`Africa/Casablanca`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa/Casablanca), or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 3-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( z );  // Get current date for a particular time zone.
```

#### Specific date

Or specify a date. You may set the month by a number, with sane numbering 1-12 for January-December, unlike the crazy zero-based numbering in the legacy class.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( 1986 , 2 , 23 ) ;  // Both year and month have same numbering. 1986 is the year 1986. 1-12 is January-December.
```

Or, better, use the [`Month`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/Month.html) enum objects pre-defined, one for each month of the year. Tip: Use these `Month` objects throughout your codebase rather than a mere integer number to make your code more self-documenting, ensure valid values, and provide [type-safety](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_safety).

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( 1986 , Month.FEBRUARY , 23 ) ;
```

#### Strings

Generate a String representing the date value in standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format by calling `toString`: YYYY-MM-DD. For other formats, see [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) class.

```
String output = ld.toString() ;  // Generate a string in standard ISO 8601 format, YYYY-MM-DD.
```

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

```
String months[] = { "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug",
        "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec" };

Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

System.out.print("Date: ");
System.out.print(months[calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH)]);
System.out.print(" " + calendar.get(Calendar.DATE) + " ");
System.out.println(calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR));

System.out.print("Time: ");
System.out.print(calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR) + ":");
System.out.print(calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE) + ":");
System.out.println(calendar.get(Calendar.SECOND));

calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR, 10);
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 29);
calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 22);

System.out.print("Updated time: ");
System.out.print(calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR) + ":");
System.out.print(calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE) + ":");
System.out.println(calendar.get(Calendar.SECOND));
```